# How do I download an entire CVS repository?

Tags: cvs, tortoisecvs

I would like to download an entire CVS repository anonymously. I have never used CVS before, but downloaded TortoiseCVS on Windows and am looking for a way to download [this](http://cvsdtusat.it.dtu.dk/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/?cvsroot=DTUsat1#dirlist) repository. When I try to create a new module for a directory in Windows and paste in the URL, it fails. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the format, that URL probably offers only ViewCVS and is not a true repository URL usable by a CVS client.

A quick google search shows a document from that publisher, which provided the repository URL, but also says in the same document that a CVS account is required.

```
This section describes how the target is built. To download the files, the user must have a cvs-account and cvs-program to the dtusat-cvs. When this is obtained, the user should run these commands, setting the cvs-enviroment up. It is only necessary to run the commands once.
export CVSROOT=:pserver:<username>@cvsdtusat.it.dtu.dk:/home/cvs/repository
cvs login
Now, the directory you are standing in (for example: /home/<username>/cvs) makes the root of the root of the filestructure you are downloading. Now type
cvs checkout dev/onboard
cvs checkout dev/ecos
cvs checkout dev/protocol
cvs checkout dev/util
```

[Google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aDdLIWFl9U_gJ%3adtusat.dtu.dk/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/%2acheckout%2a/onboard/DOC/building.tex%3Frev%3DHEAD+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)